# Separating a string into integers and storing sum and averages

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

JavaScript; I want to get the values in a string which always has the following format but also has an indeterminate number of variables:

Sample String `"340=5;339=5;338=3;337=4;336=1;335=4;334=4;333=4"`

The variables named as `340`, `339`, `338` etc. in this string store integer values such as `5`, `4`, `1` and so on. I want to extract the integer values for each of the variables (extracting what's after the equal signs) and store the sum and average value of them in two separate variables as "sum" and "avr".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing fancy, hopefully nice and readable.

```
function calculate(myString) {
    var values = myString.split(';');
    var sum = 0;
    values.forEach(function(el, i) {
        sum += parseInt(el.split('=')[1]);
    });

    return {
        sum: sum,
        avg: sum / values.length
    }
}

var results = calculate("340=5;339=5;338=3;337=4;336=1;335=4;334=4;333=4");

console.log(results.sum); // => 30
console.log(results.avg); // => 3.75
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have a simple pattern, you can use a *RegExp* to find the bits of interest. Here is an example using [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var str = "340=5;339=5;338=3;337=4;336=1;335=4;334=4;333=4";

var parts = (';'+str).split(/;\d+=/).slice(1), // passing the RegExp to .split
    sum = parts.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
        return prev + +cur; // notice String cur to Number
    }, 0),
    avr = sum / parts.length; // assuming you want mean average

console.log(sum, avr); // 30 3.75
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string then loop through all the values to get the sum and average.

```js
var str="340=5;339=5;338=3;337=4;336=1;335=4;334=4;333=4";

var array =str.split(/;?\d+=/g);
var sum=0;
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  if(!isNaN(parseInt(array[i])))
    sum+=parseInt(array[i]);
  else{
    array.splice(i,1);
    i--;
  }
}

console.log(sum);
console.log(sum/array.length);
```

Comment: If you loop towards zero you can avoid having to move `i` around when removing an item from your _Array_

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial string evaluation. The only method you need is split, and the only logic you need is a for loop.

```
var values = "340=5;339=5;338=3;337=4;336=1;335=4;334=4;333=4";
var sum = []
var avr = []

values = values.split(';');

for(i=0; i<values.length; i++){
  numbers = values[i].split('=')
  sum.push(numbers[0])
  avr.push(numbers[1])
}
```